# UK visit visa for Nigerian

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, nigerian-citizens, nigeria

I am a Nigerian who has been invited to the UK for assessment by the British Army.

I would like to know how I could prove I have funds, as I haven't put funds into my account but I have 2 sponsors (1 in the UK) and 1 in the USA.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! I suggest you look at previous questions and answers on this topic as there have been several: https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=british+army

Answer (score 3):

Note that in addition to the funds required, you need to show ties to your home country, so they can be confident you are going to leave the UK as planned, at least in the case you do not pass assessment.

This usually means having a stable, well paid job (by UK standards) or a successful business, or substantial property or savings, etc.

But “I want to join the Army in the UK” clearly signals that whatever ties you may have in your country, you are willing to leave all of that behind you, so you probably need to have a strong application in this respect.

I strongly recommend you read [the guide for non-UK nationals](https://a.storyblok.com/f/88791/x/056f27dc19/adr009539_nonuk_guide_part1_.pdf) before you go any further, and make good note of all the warnings it contains.

Comment: Thank you Sir 
1.>I got my UK Sponsor’s 1-Month Statement & Letter  and also my Brother’s (in the USA) 6 months Statement, Pay Slips and a Letter also. 

2.> I have a Job that pays cash and stated that but it is just a little bit over the minimum wage in Nigeria. 

Pls Based off of these info… would you recommend any adjustments or additional Documents? 

Thanks once more

Comment: @t-boy I don’t think a 1-month statement will do any good. While I don’t think there is any official guidance on the topic, the unwritten rule is that they should cover at the very least 3 months, and ideally 6 months. If you are paid cash your best option is to deposit the full amount onto bank account every time you are paid (so that it matches pay slips). But earning so little compared to UK living standards does not make your application very strong. Put yourself in the does of the ECO: they will think you just want to get into the UK and live and work there under the radar.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot

Comment: Basically, my Sponsor in the UK is only providing Accommodation and feeding. 
Do I need need more Bank statements? 

- As for my Salary, yes I deposit the sum and I get more money from other sources on a monthly Basis and it  reflects on my account. And I have to apply this Week because I need to be there by February. 

Pls What do you think Sir?                                            Do I try to persuade him for statements for at least 3 Months?

Answer (score 1):

If you have sponsors who are prepared to pay the full cost of your trip to the UK then you do not necessarily need to show that you have the money yourself.

You would need to include financial statements for your two sponsors to show that they have the necessary funds, and statements from them that they are prepared to do so. You also need an explanation of why they are prepared to give you this money. You also need to include your own financial statements.

Be aware that even with all these it is far from guaranteed that your application will be accepted.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
Please what would you suggest I added to my application to increase my chances of Approval? 
Thank you

Comment: 1.> Thanks a Lot Sir. 
I got my UK Sponsor’s 1-Month Statement & Letter  and also my Brother’s (in the USA) 6 months Statement, Pay Slips and a Letter also. 

2.> I have a Job that pays cash and stated that but it is just a little bit over the minimum wage in Nigeria. 

Pls Based off of these info… would you recommend any adjustments or additional Documents? 

Thanks once more

Comment: Try to get more months of finance documents from your UK sponsor.